# Convert text to dates in excel

Tags: excel

I've done all of I can in excel to extract the date from this text "Mon Nov 03 10:07:06 2014" Can anyone help me regarding with this? I want to get the date in this form e.g 11/3/2014 and once I click format cells I will be able to change its date format.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you show the codes you have used to try to extract the date, and tell us how it failed?

Comment: I guess you have a lot of dates like this? Do they always have the first three letters of the day & month?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! Here is the code that I used =DATEVALUE(MID(A1,4,15)) but excel will return values like these "11/03/2015" which is the year in the data is 2014.

Comment: Hi Tom, yes in my data it always have the first three letters of the day and month. That's why i think its kinda difficult to extract the dates.

Comment: I've already used text to column also to extract the data, and concatenate them together but the dates can't change it's format because it comes as text.

Answer (score 2):

you could work with `left` and `right` to extract the values. Afterwards you can convert it to date with `date`. here is a solution, maybe not the best:

`=DATE(RIGHT(H47;4);MONTH("1"&RIGHT(LEFT(H47;7);3));RIGHT(LEFT(H47;10);2))`

cell `H47` = `"Mon Nov 03 10:07:06 2014"`

result = `03.11.2014`

I hope it helps.

best - AB

Comment: Nice way to get the month !

Comment: Cool answer bro. But it can never be change when I click format cells. Anyway thank you bro!

Answer (score 1):

With data in **A1**, in another cell enter:

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,8,3)&"-"&MID(A1,5,3)&"-"&RIGHT(A1,4))
```

and format this cell as *Date:*

[image]

The key is to create a string that *Datevalue()* will accept!

Comment: Woahhh nice work bro, it already convert the date. Thank you so much.